# Display change breaks transitions

Tags: html, css, animation, optimization, transition

I don't know why, but changing display property of parent breaks transitions on child elements.

**HTML**

```
<div class="grandfather">
    <div class="father">
        <div class="child1 children"></div>
        <div class="child2 children"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grandfather{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
}

.father{
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}

.grandfather:hover .father{
    display: block;
}

.child1,
.child2{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.grandfather:hover .children{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bdu3fno2/5/

**NOTE:** I know that changing display is not necessary in this particular case, I could just change the opacity and it'd work well, but it's interesting to know, why browsers behave like this - is this some sort of optimization? I don't think that's part of CSS specification.

Comment: Use `visibility:hidden` / `visibility:visible` instead of display. As you see, transitions don't work with display changes

Comment: ...As for *why* display changes cause transitions not to work - that's probably because there's *no way* to transition between them due to the layout changes that they entail. The `visibility` property is different in that you're not changing layout - just showing/hiding what's already there.

Answer (score 1):

use `opacity` with `visibility`

```css
.grandfather {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}
.father {
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
.grandfather:hover .father {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.child1,
.child2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
.grandfather:hover .children {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandfather">
  <div class="father">
    <div class="child1 children"></div>
    <div class="child2 children"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```